# Puppeteer: is there a way to access the DevTools Network API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I am trying to use [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) for end-to-end tests. These tests require accessing the network emulation capabilities of DevTools (e.g. to simulate offline browsing).

So far I am using chrome-remote-interface, but it is too low-level for my taste.

As far as I know, Puppeteer does not expose the network DevTools features (`emulateNetworkConditions` in the DevTools protocol).

Is there an escape hatch in Puppeteer to access those features, e.g. a way to execute a Javascript snippet in a context in which the DevTools API is accessible?

Thanks

**Edit:**
OK, so it seems that I can work around the lack of an API using something like this:

```
    const client = page._client;
    const res = await client.send('Network.emulateNetworkConditions',
      { offline: true, latency: 40, downloadThroughput: 40*1024*1024, 
      uploadThroughput: 40*1024*1024 });
```

But I suppose it is Bad Form and may slip under my feet at any time?

Comment: Not any time, I guess, but only when the underlying API is changed in an unexpected way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**: headless Chrome now supports network throttling!

In Puppeteer, you can emulate devices (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageemulateoptions) but not network conditions. It's something we're considering, but headless Chrome needs to support network throttling first.

To emulate a device, I'd use the predefined devices found in `DeviceDescriptors`:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const devices = require('puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors');
const iPhone = devices['iPhone 6'];

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.emulate(iPhone);
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
  // other actions...
  browser.close();
});
```

Comment: OK, I did not know that headless Chrome couldn't be throttled. As for the ability to send raw protocol messages to a page, is it going to be exposed at some point? Or will it stay as it is, or be hidden within a closure or something? Basically, can I rely on it?

Comment: @ebidel as it was added to chromium, how can we use it ?
 https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/8931a104b145ccf92390f6f48fba6553a1af92e4%5E%21/#F0

Comment: Should work out of the box now. What are you seeing?

Comment: I don't know if this is a valid question, but I've ready of Headless chrome not supporting network throttling, but I haven't read anything about supporting the network throttling on a NON-headless mode of puppeteer. Can anyone explain to me please?

Comment: Hi ickyrr, throttling works on the non-headless mode of puppeteer. See the workaround on the original question.